# Issue accessing website on internal network

Tags: domain-name-system, resolution

Been working on this problem for a while and have had no luck so far...
Environment: 
  Server 2008R2
  AD & DNS (DHCP supplied by router)
  Static IP  with 127.0.0.1 and router IP as DNS
  Host https portions of a website.  Non HTTPS portions hosted outside our internal network.
  DNS has members.mydomain.net as a forward lookup zone, with SOA and NS records pointing to server.mydomain.local (this server)

Problem 1: On any public network, everything works fine.  On the internal network, I cannot pull up any of the HTTPS portions of the website.  It comes back with a Page Not Found.
NSLOOKUP

```
C:\Users\Administrator>nslookup
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  ::1

> set debug
> members.mydomain.net
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  ::1

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        members.mydomain.net.mydomain.local, type = A, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  mydomain.local
        ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
        primary name server = server.mydomain.local
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.mydomain.local
        serial  = 2517
        refresh = 900 (15 mins)
        retry   = 600 (10 mins)
        expire  = 86400 (1 day)
        default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        members.mydomain.net.mydomain.local, type = AAAA, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  mydomain.local
        ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
        primary name server = server.mydomain.local
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.mydomain.local
        serial  = 2517
        refresh = 900 (15 mins)
        retry   = 600 (10 mins)
        expire  = 86400 (1 day)
        default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 4, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        members.mydomain.net, type = A, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  members.mydomain.net
        ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
        primary name server = server.mydomain.local
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.mydomain.local
        serial  = 1
        refresh = 900 (15 mins)
        retry   = 600 (10 mins)
        expire  = 86400 (1 day)
        default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 5, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        members.mydomain.net, type = AAAA, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  members.mydomain.net
        ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
        primary name server = server.mydomain.local
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.mydomain.local
        serial  = 1
        refresh = 900 (15 mins)
        retry   = 600 (10 mins)
        expire  = 86400 (1 day)
        default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
Name:    members.mydomain.net
```

Thing is, this was all working fine a few months ago.  I know changes have been made (new router, new SSL cert, possibly some other bits), but nothing on the DNS config of the server has been changed.  Client is getting frustrated that he can't use his site in his own network.  Any help would be appreciated.

Problem 2: Similar, but not quite...
remote.mydomain.com points to RDP on this server.  Works fine from outside the internal network.  Pings to our external IP address from inside the network, but when used as an address for an RDP session, says the computer is not responding or not setup for remote.
remote.mydomain.com does NOT have any entries in our own DNS on this server.  Relies simply on external address.  Again, this worked as well, but now it doesn't.

I'm stumped, in that both problems are similar, but I suspect indicate different issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, `members.mydomain.net` should be resolving to the IP address of a server on the LAN when queried from the LAN. If that's accurate, create an "A" record with a blank hostname in the `members.mydomain.net` DNS forward lookup zone resolving to the IP address of the machine hosting the `membbers.mydomain.net` website.

As far as your `remote.mydomain.net` name goes, create a forward lookup zone named `remote.mydomain.net` and the same type of "A" record as above (except, obviously, using the IP address of the machine hosting RDP).

I'm guessing there was an "A" record in the `membbers.mydomain.net` zone at one time that somebody deleted mistakenly.